# ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_csp_header' from 'werkzeug.http' (C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py)

Tags: python, anaconda, tf.keras

I am getting this error by running tenserbord

> (base) C:\Users\karan\TF_2_Notebooks_and_Data\03-ANNs>tensorboard
>   --logdir logs\fit Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard-script.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from tensorboard.main import run_main   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line
>   40, in 
>       from tensorboard import default   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\audio_plugin.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from werkzeug import wrappers   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug__init__.py",
>   line 151, in 
>       **import**('werkzeug.exceptions')   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py",
>   line 71, in 
>       from werkzeug.wrappers import Response   File "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers__init__.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from .common_descriptors import CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin   File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\common_descriptors.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from ..http import dump_csp_header ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_csp_header' from 'werkzeug.http'
>   (C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py)

and also by running,

```
board = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_directory,histogram_freq=1,
    write_graph=True,
    write_images=True,
    update_freq='epoch',
    profile_batch=2,embeddings_freq=1)
```

if I put `embeddings_freq=1` instead of `embeddings_freq=0` then I get an error

> Train on 426 samples, validate on 143 samples Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py",
>   line 1561, in _configure_embeddings
>       from tensorboard.plugins import projector
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector__init__.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       from tensorboard.plugins.projector import projector_plugin as _projector_plugin
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\projector\projector_plugin.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       from werkzeug import wrappers
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug__init__.py",
>   line 151, in 
>       **import**('werkzeug.exceptions')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py",
>   line 71, in 
>       from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers__init__.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from .common_descriptors import CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\common_descriptors.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from ..http import dump_csp_header
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_csp_header' from 'werkzeug.http'
>   (C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 5, in 
>       callbacks=[board,early_stop]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 819, in fit
>       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py",
>   line 307, in fit
>       mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py",
>   line 107, in configure_callbacks
>       callback_list.set_model(callback_model)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py",
>   line 222, in set_model
>       callback.set_model(model)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py",
>   line 1549, in set_model
>       self._configure_embeddings()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\karan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py",
>   line 1563, in _configure_embeddings
>       raise ImportError('Failed to import TensorBoard. Please make sure that '
>
> ImportError: Failed to import TensorBoard. Please make sure that
>   TensorBoard integration is complete."

What should I do> I am not an expert just a beginner, and I didn't create an anaconda env, I am running it in a (base), can someone please reply it fast? My exams are coming and I need to resolve this as fast it could be, my thanks to the community.